# Rewarded ad showresult remain finished even after you reward the player

Tags: unity

When the user dies in game and if they watch a rewarded ad video I give them 3 health. Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class adScript : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsListener
{

    public string gameId = "xxxx";
    string mySurfacingId = "Rewarded_Android";
    [SerializeField] private GameObject LoadingUI = null;
    public float waitTime = 3f;
    public bool testMode = true;
    public GameObject dead;
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject blue;

    void Start()
    {
        // Initialize the Ads service:
        Advertisement.AddListener(this);
        Advertisement.Initialize(gameId, testMode);
    }

    public void ShowInterstitialAd()
    {
        if (Advertisement.IsReady())
        {
            Advertisement.Show("Interstitial_Android");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error: Ad was not able to be loaded in " + waitTime + " seconds!");
            Debug.Log("Ad didnt loaded");
        }
    }

    //private IEnumerator ShowAd()
    //{
    //    float currentTime = 0.0f;

    //    LoadingUI.SetActive(true);

    //    while (currentTime <= waitTime && !Advertisement.IsReady())
    //    {
    //        currentTime += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
            
    //        yield return null;
    //    }

    //    // show the ad if it is now ready
    //    if (Advertisement.IsReady())
    //    {
    //        Advertisement.Show("Interstitial_Android");
    //    }
    //    else
    //    {
    //        Debug.LogError("Error: Ad was not able to be loaded in " + waitTime + " seconds!");
    //        Debug.Log("Ad didnt loaded");
    //    }

    //    LoadingUI.SetActive(false);
    //}
    public void ShowRewardedVideo()
    {
        // Check if UnityAds ready before calling Show method:
        if (Advertisement.IsReady(mySurfacingId))
        {
            Advertisement.Show(mySurfacingId);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Rewarded video is not ready at the moment! Please try again later!");
        }
    }

    // Implement IUnityAdsListener interface methods:
    public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string surfacingId, ShowResult showResult)
    {
        // Define conditional logic for each ad completion status:
        if (showResult == ShowResult.Finished)
        {
            showResult = 0;
            healthScript.healthValue += 3;
            respawn();
            player.SetActive(true);
            dead.SetActive(false);
        }
        else if (showResult == ShowResult.Skipped)
        {
            
        }
        else if (showResult == ShowResult.Failed)
        {
        }
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsReady(string surfacingId)
    {
        // If the ready Ad Unit or legacy Placement is rewarded, show the ad:
        if (surfacingId == mySurfacingId)
        {
            // Optional actions to take when theAd Unit or legacy Placement becomes ready (for example, enable the rewarded ads button)
        }
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidError(string message)
    {
        // Log the error.
    }

    public void OnUnityAdsDidStart(string surfacingId)
    {
        // Optional actions to take when the end-users triggers an ad.
    }

    // When the object that subscribes to ad events is destroyed, remove the listener:
    public void OnDestroy()
    {
        Advertisement.RemoveListener(this);
    }

    public void respawn()
    {

        Renderer rend = player.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        TrailRenderer rend2 = player.GetComponent<TrailRenderer>();
        Collider2D col = player.GetComponent<Collider2D>();

        gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        rend.enabled = true;
        rend2.enabled = true;
        col.enabled = true;
        blue.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }

}
```

In this code dead is for the deadMenu and screen is another menu for user to click on button to continue game.

Issue is the works fine. But when I pause the game after all this than the user gets the health bonus again because the `Debug.LogWarning("showsResult");` is finished again and the above code runs again.

How to tackle it?

Comment: Then don't call this code again when you pause the game? It's hard to tell you where the issue lies as it is not apparent that it is with the code you're showing us here. You should probably set a breakpoint there and see the callstack to tell you what's going on there.

Comment: I dont think the call it but why is the ad status is finished even after it already has rewarded player?

Comment: Because you did not change the value of `showResult`, presumably? We don't know how this code is invoked so we can't tell. Please provide all the code necessary to reproduce the issue; this will help us debug it (instead of guessing).

Comment: @Vaillancourt Check the update bro

Comment: How/where do you call `ShowRewardedVideo`? Do you call this multiple times? (Also, I'm not your bro, you might want to avoid calling random people "bro" or [assume their gender in general](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/conduct).)

Comment: First I didnt assumed your gender as bro is universal but if u mind it Sorry my bad. I have Interstitial ad on my pause button so after getting rewarded the first time when user press the pause button they get rewarded again so i removed that ad and it worked. Can you please tell me how to change showResult value.

Comment: It seems that you have two ways to call up an ad, are they both invoked at the same time? Or you have this code on two game objects that show an ad? If you don't want your functions to be called after an ad is run (which would be odd), you might want to remove it from the listeners list `Advertisement.RemoveListener(this);`. You might want to put breakpoints on those `Show` methods and see how they're called. Finally, regarding "bro", [the term is not really inclusive/gender neutral](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bro), but no harm done in this case :)

Comment: i have this script on just one game object. I have added buttons than i attach this script to that button when user clicks on the pause button it runs the  public void ShowInterstitialAd() as i have selected and when user click on show video ad button I run the ShowRewardedVideo() ad.

Comment: Okay, so you want it so that when the user clicks on the pause button, `ShowInterstitialAd` is called and `healthValue` is _not_ increased (no reward for using pause), but when the user dies (or something), you call `ShowRewardedVideo` to allow the user to get a reward as an increase of `healthValue` so that they keep on playing? You want to use the same script for both ad displays (in both situations)?

Comment: yes I am using the same script. Now what happens is that 1. I start game 2. I pause it 3.It shows an ad so it works fine 4. I die and than i chose to watch rewarded ad 5. I get +3 health and game goes on 6.I click on pause button and now i get +3 health again after i close ad.

Comment: Okay, could you try something: instead of checking this: `if (showResult == ShowResult.Finished)`, check this instead: `if (showResult == ShowResult.Finished && surfacingId == mySurfacingId)`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH ITS BEEN ALL DAY I WAS DYING. THANK YOU. BLESS YOU

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that you use the same code to run the Unity ads in two different ways, but don't tell Unity that they should not behave the same.

You say that you want `ShowInterstitialAd()` to just show an ad and move on, and `ShowRewardedVideo()` show an ad and reward the player when they're done consuming it.

There is nothing currently in your code that says this, you need to tell Unity about this. When you call `Advertisement.Show()`, Unity will check what to show, show it to the player and when they're done consuming the ad, Unity will you about it. It will send the parameter you passed to `Show()` to your `OnUnityAdsDidFinish()` implementation as the first parameter: you can then check what this parameter is and act upon it; in your case, since you show the advertisement you want rewarded like this `Advertisement.Show(mySurfacingId);`, you would need something like this in `OnUnityAdsDidFinish()`:

```
    public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string surfacingId, ShowResult showResult)
    {
        // Define conditional logic for each ad completion status:
        if (showResult == ShowResult.Finished && surfacingId == mySurfacingId)
        {
            showResult = 0;
            healthScript.healthValue += 3;
            respawn();
            player.SetActive(true);
            dead.SetActive(false);
        }
        else if (showResult == ShowResult.Skipped)
        {
            
        }
        else if (showResult == ShowResult.Failed)
        {
        }
    }
```